# How to make only placeholder italics in tailwind css?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I want to have an input text box that has only the placeholder as italics but not the text content.

I know we can do this using normal css like so:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   font-style: italic;
}
```

But how to do it in tailwind way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Placeholder state is built-in as of Tailwind CSS v. 3.0. [Check the docs here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#placeholder-text=)

#### Use like this:

```html
<input type="text" class="placeholder:italic" />
```

See a working example: [Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/2KWEhX2Piq?file=config)

#### Looks like this

[image: Italic placeholder]

---

### Original Tailwind CSS 2 answer

#### Define like this

```css
@layer utilities {
  .placeholder-italic::placeholder{
    @apply italic
  }
}
```

#### Use like this

```html
<input type="text" class="placeholder-italic" />
```

See a working example: [Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/DxdYqAonjq?file=css)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not found an existing Tailwind utility to change the font-style property, but in Tailwind you can create your custom utilities.

```css
@layer utilities {
  .italic-plc::placeholder {
     font-style: italic;
  }
}
```

TailwindCSS related doc page: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-new-utilities

Comment: This will also make the value italic; not just the placeholder

Comment: @tauzN you're right, I forgot to add ```::placeholder```. Now I've correct my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use `placeholder-shown:italic`

Working example: [Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/l4US9YHYm8)

Answer (score 1):

**In Tailwind v3.0**

If you want to make it bold.

```
<input type="text" class="placeholder:font-bold" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
<input class="placeholder:italic placeholder:text-gray-400" />
```

[Check out the docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#placeholder-text)